# Not able to assign local variable value to Global variable in Python Selenium automation - POM

Tags: python, selenium, variables

I have a global variable named global_my_gift_card = "", and I want to update the value of the same variable from local variable (created inside method), I am trying to do this, but global variable is not getting updated.

Below is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class Create_Giftcard:

    giftcardtype_dropdown_xpath = "//select[@id='GiftCardTypeId']"
    activated_checkbox_xpath = "//input[@class='check-box']"
    generatecode_button_xpath = "//button[@id='generateCouponCode']"
    cuponcode_field_xpath = "//input[@id='GiftCardCouponCode']"
    recepiantname_field_xpath = "//input[@id='RecipientName']"
    save_button_xpath = "//button[@name='save']"

    global_my_gift_card = ""

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver


    def test_create_new_giftcard(self, gc_type, gc_rec_name):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        gctype = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.giftcardtype_dropdown_xpath)
        sel = Select(gctype)
        sel.select_by_visible_text(gc_type)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.activated_checkbox_xpath).click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.generatecode_button_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(3)
        global global_my_gift_card
        my_gift_card = 
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.cuponcode_field_xpath).get_attribute('value')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.recepiantname_field_xpath).send_keys(gc_rec_name)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.save_button_xpath).click()
        self.global_my_gift_card = my_gift_card + ""
        print(global_my_gift_card, "Outside")enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `global` statement that you used in the `test_create_new_giftcard` function

```
global global_my_gift_card
```

indicates that an identifier belongs to the **module**'s scope, but the `global_my_gift_card` variable has been created in the `Create_Giftcard` **class** scope. So you should remove the `global` statement, and refer to your variable as `Create_Giftcard.global_my_gift_card` instead of `self.global_my_gift_card` (you might want to rename it as well).

Comment: Hi Joao, no luck with this,

Comment: Hey @joao.. It worked dear, its my bad, i was referring to wrong variable, thanks for the help